# How to remove permanent/pre-installed Chromium extensions in Linux?

Tags: linux, chrome, delete

I am using Chromium (not Chrome) under Debian 9. How can I remove this extension:

[image]

[image]

Obviously, it cannot be removed by clicking "remove" and it cannot be found under its ID in

```
/home/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/
```

Is is stored elsewhere or maybe even 'hardcoded' into the Chromium source code?

Comment: It's not a "real" extension, it just shows up as one.  It's built in, and so can't be removed.  It's the component that handles 2FA logins.  Chrome also has it, but doesn't show it by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Debian version of Chromium shows you all the extensions that are built into Chromium and that would be normally hidden in a build of Chrome.  This is to provide transparency about what is being used.

This extension is part of Chromium and provides the ability to use a hardware token like Yubikey to authenticate to a website, and it cannot be removed.  While it, like many other extensions, does have the *ability* to view all of your website data, it isn't invasive of privacy and is generally unoffensive.